# gulp build fails with chalk version : 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, gulp, chalk

Got the below issue after the chalk version updated from 2.4.2 to 3.0.0. The gulp build fails resulting in production build failure.

```
--- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:gulp (gulp build) @ vcedpa ---
[INFO] Running 'gulp.js build' in /auto/builds/idpa/main/640037/vcedpa-war/../ui
[ERROR] /auto/builds/idpa/main/640037/ui/node_modules/run-sequence/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js:3
[ERROR] const {stdout: stdoutColor, stderr: stderrColor} = require('supports-color');
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
[ERROR] at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
[ERROR] at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
[ERROR] at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
[ERROR] at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
[ERROR] at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
[ERROR] at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
[ERROR] at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
[ERROR] at Object. (/auto/builds/idpa/main/640037/ui/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:5:14)
[ERROR] at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
[ERROR] at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

Immediate answer will be much appreciated.
```

Comment: Upgrade your version of Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the seem issue, downgrading back to 2.4.2 solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly post your `gulpfile.js`? As Gulp itself is just a task runner, your `gulpfile.js` might help us determine *where* it's failing.

Just looking at the error itself, it seems that gulp here may be having an issue with object destructuring (which the source code of chalk.js version 2.4.2 does *not* seem to use). I personally have had some recent issues with `gulp-babel` and/or `gulp-uglify` not working correctly and basically complaining about modern JavaScript features, and have had to replace `gulp-uglify` with `terser`.

My guess would be that whatever minification/uglification library you're using has not been updated, and thus doesn't "get" object destructuring.